# Structs in C - need some advise

Tags: c, struct

I run into something like this in C:

```
struct{
int a;
int b;
} cmd = {1,1);
```

What is this? is `cmd` is the name of the struct? the name of the variable? how can it be both? can you make more variables of this struct?

Comment: You just have a variable named `cmd`.  If you want `cmd` to be both the name of the struct and a variable, you can do that with: `struct cmd { int a; int b; } cmd;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a variable named `cmd` whose type is an *anonymous struct*.

Because the structure type doesn't have a name or `typedef` alias, this means it can't be used as a parameter to a function, and that no other variables of this type can be defined except in the same declaration as `cmd`.

Also, note that you have a syntax error in the initializer for `cmd`.  Instead of `{1,1)` it should be `{1,1}`.